# Appium app closing after the test case execution

Tags: testng, appium

I am writing a testNG test suit where I am starting two different apps. 1. Gmail
2. Google maps.
My code works fine, also my test cases are executing properly. But, after the end of Google map is automatically going into background. What can I do to keep app running in foreground?

Comment: Are you setting the timeout for your driver? I know, when I don't set my timeout, the app drops into the background after the default(30 seconds I think). Here is the code in Java. desiredCapability.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.NEW_COMMAND_TIMEOUT, 300); IOSDriver ios = new IOSDriver("http://localhost:4723/wd/hub", dc);

Comment: Hey I did try using desiredCapability.se‌​tCapability(MobileCap‌​abilityType.NEW_COMMA‌​ND_TIMEOUT, 300); but that doen't help